# Modesty of the other side

Tags: tznius-modesty, tractate-brachot, tzadok-hakohen-lublin

Rav Tzadok haCohen in Peri Tzaddik on *Vayishlach*, section 11, last paragraph, discusses that Persian/Medean exile corresponds to *Yaakov avinu*.

In passing, he discusses the Talmud (*Bavli Berachos* 8b) which first quotes Rabban Gamliel who says that he likes 3 aspects of Persian conduct because they are modest, and right after, the Talmud quotes Rav Yosef that the Persians are designated for *Gehinnom*.

Rav Tzadok resolves the seeming contradiction by saying that their modesty leads them to *Gehinnom* because it is not *migeder kedushah*.

Could someone please explain what he means, and possibly explain how modesty (when not applied in a fake way to lead to more immodesty) can be not from the aspect of *kedushah*?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you please cite the original passages from both R"Z and the Gemmorahs.

Comment: @AlBerko I am not sure how else you would like me to cite -- I gave very detailed pointers to where to find the passages

Comment: Just bring the citations in the original Hebrew it inside the question, without the need of external readings.

Comment: @AlBerko you're looking for the word "quote" not "cite". He correctly cited his source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably he's referencing the Gemara in [Kesubos 48A](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.48a?lang=bi), that the default understanding when a couple gets married is to provide skin-on-skin contact to one another. If one party were to insist on remaining fully clothed even during intimacy -- "as the Persians do" -- and the other side objected, that would be grounds for divorce. In short -- excessive modesty that comes at the expense of being kind to others.

Comment: https://www.timesofisrael.com/a-year-since-leaders-death-ultra-orthodox-cult-hibernates-in-central-america/

Comment: @Loewian Couples must be fully un-clothed during relations, as per the halacha brought down in the Gemara. Either Lev Tahor is not performing the halacha, or the reporters are spreading rumors and sensational stories.

Comment: @ezra with permission it is permitted or maybe even perfered  דבשניהם מרוצים הוי מדת צניעות, https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.240.22